# Trying to execute a shell script as another user from another shell script

Tags: bash, ubuntu

```
Ubuntu 18.04
```

I have one shell script: doit.sh that copies a shell script to another user's home folder, and then tries to run it. I tried multiple combinations, but it's not working.

doit.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo mv testsh.sh /home/test3
sudo chown test3:test3 /home/test3/testsh.sh
sudo -i -u test3 bash << EOF
testsh='testsh.sh'
exec $testsh
EOF
```

testsh.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "export RAILS_ENV='rails_env'" |  tee test3.4 >/dev/null
```

testsh.sh was moved to /home/test3, but the test3.4 file was not created in /home/test3 and I am not getting any error messages. Any idea if this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$testsh` is being expanded by the original shell, not the shell run by `sudo`. You need quote the `EOF` token to prevent variable expansion in the here-doc.

```
sudo -i -u test3 bash << 'EOF'
testsh='testsh.sh'
exec $testsh
EOF
```

But I'm not sure why you need that variable, you can just do:

```
sudo -i -u test3 /home/test3/testsh.sh
```

Comment: I did not realize I can simply execute that shell script as the other user. Your solution is missing the bash command to execute the shell. Without it, I get an error message. This solves the problem I'm having

Comment: There's no need for the `bash` command, that's done automatically by `#!/bin/bash` in the script.

Comment: Make sure you `chmod 755 testsh.sh`

Comment: I kept getting an error message: testsh.sh: command not found. When I added bash, it worked. This is on Ubuntu 18.04. I checked and the x flag was set for all

Comment: Make sure `testsh.sh` has Unix newlines, not Windows newlines.

Comment: Did you use the absolute pathname like I wrote?

Comment: I did. Even when I try to execute doit.sh, by typing doit.sh, I get an error message. 755 is set, I made sure of that. This is weird. The next issue for me, is to figure out how to export a variable from shell 2, to shell 2. Not sure it's possible, since shell 2 will be running as a different user

Comment: ... and I did use the absolute pathname

Comment: You can't run scripts by just typing the name, it has to be a path, e.g. `./doit.sh`, because `.` is not usually in `$PATH`.

Comment: Did you check the newlines? This problem often happens if the file has carriage returns instead of line feed. Use `dos2unix testsh.sh`

Comment: I will double check for newlines, but I am using a Mac, and for the scripts I'm running, I created them directly using Vi, when I was connected to the AWS Ubuntu server via terminal from my Mac Laptop.

Comment: Then that shouldn't be a problem, it usually happens when creating the file on Windows and then copying.